# ASP.NET MVC Rotativa.ViewAsPdf Generate Mobile View(I want Full Size)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf, rotativa

I need to Generate Pdf from View . 
I am using Rotativa but Always Generate Mobile Size (View file include bootsrap).
How can I disable resize in Rotativa .
 My Code is :

```
 ViewAsPdf pdf = new ViewAsPdf("DownloadViewPDF", property)
        {

            FileName = "Angel" + ".pdf",
            PageOrientation = Orientation.Landscape,
            PageMargins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0),
            PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
            CustomSwitches = "--disable-smart-shrinking"


        };


        return pdf;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove bootstrap or you can give link ref to bootstrap in  element in your cshtml for which you are generating pdf